# Can Hbase shell be accessed from remote client, or only by SSH connection?

Tags: database, hbase, remote-access

I have set up a standalone HBase server,  just to practice and learn. Let's say, the IP address of the Hbase server (where I can run Hbase shell from console) is x.x.x.x.

On machine x.x.x.x I also installed a SSH server.

I wonder, if I can connect to HBase server, with some special command from another machine (y.y.y.y) or I only can SSH from y.y.y.y to x.x.x.x and then run HBase shell?

For example, with MongoDB, I was ablo to cennect with: `mongo -u admin -p
student x.x.x.x:27017/admin` and I was able to test the database. I'm looking the same way how can I connect to a remote HBase shell instance. Im using newest Linux Mint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can install hbase on machine `y.y.y.y` and set the configuration to point to the hbase running on the `x.x.x.x` machine and run the hbase shell. The configuration should be added to a file called `hbase-site.xml` which is present in the `$HBASE_HOME/conf` directory

```xml
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum<name>
      <value>x.x.x.x</value>
   </property>
  <property>
      <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
      <value>2181</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

These properties tell the hbase client running on `y.y.y.y` that it should connect to `x.x.x.x:2181` to lookup the hbase cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hbase shell -Dhbase.zookeeper.quorum="host1,host2,host3" -Dzookeeper.znode.parent="/hbase" -Dhbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2181
```